# Compiling/Package a Shoes.app to a standalone Mac.app?

Tags: ruby, shoes

Is there a way to package a Shoes.app to a standalone Mac.app?

Comment: did you try to use packager? with it you can package your app for winsows\linux\macos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shoes maintainer here! There are three ways to package apps with Shoes:

1. Via the GUI option. This is currently broken on OSX. Working on it.
2. Via --shy. This should work.
3. By compiling your app and Shoes together. This is what I do with Hackety Hack. Totally works.

Answer (score 0):

Granted, the documentation leaves a lot to be desired, but look at `Shoes::Pack`:

http://rdoc.info/github/why/shoes/master/Shoes/Pack

Also I haven't used Shoes since _why disappeared, but does `shoes --shy` still work?