# How to package ruby shoes apps on OSX 10.7

Tags: ruby, macos, package, shoes, dmg

I have been making an app using Ruby Shoes. I am happy with how it turned out and would like to share it with some friends. However, the GUI packager doesn't work in OSX and the Windows packager only seems to make a `.shy` file. I've been reading around looking for solutions and I don't understand any of them. Can someone clearly explain step-by-step how to package a Ruby Shoes app to say a DMG or an EXE file?

Comment: It's a .shy file extension. It's an executable file but you need to have Shoes installed to launch it. Preferably I would like to able to package .exe and .dmg files, to make distribution simpler

Comment: For the .dmg file, I think a more relevant question is how to package into a stand alone mac app. The .dmg is just a disk image--it could have anything on it--but I think what you want is a file that someone could just drag into their applications folder and run, right?

Comment: Have a look if this helps                   https://github.com/shoes/shoes/wiki/Building-Shoes-on-Mac-OS-X-10.6-and-10.7

Comment: This might help (or not) https://github.com/shoes/shoes/wiki/A-Developer%27s-Tour-Through-The-Magic-Packager

Comment: The old Raisins (V2) release of Shoes use to package to shy, exe and dmg. These options still exist but do not work and the question is how to get this functionality back.

Comment: Have you tried asking Shoes maintainer Steve Klabnik directly? http://www.steveklabnik.com/

Comment: if you right click on the .shy file and select show contents, what does that directory structure look like - what kinds of files are in there?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer to use [green_shoes](https://github.com/ashbb/green_shoes). Green_shoes is a pure ruby gem that you require in your ruby code instead of a program that packages your ruby code. This way, you can use a program such as [ocra](http://ocra.rubyforge.org/) to make your ruby file into exe. While it is sort of a hack, I feel that it is better than requiring your users to install shoes to run your program.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.
[Compiling/Package a Shoes.app to a standalone Mac.app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770446/compiling-package-a-shoes-app-to-a-standalone-mac-app)
[How?] "By compiling your app and Shoes together. This is what I do with Hackety Hack. Totally works."